# Implement non-symmetrical background image to a site

Tags: html, wordpress, css, background

I am trying to add [this 3D image](http://webbos.co/vibration/wp-content/themes/vibration-child-theme/images/back1.jpg) as background to the content of [a wordpress website](http://webbos.co/vibration/)

[This is the theme demo I'm using](http://londonthemes.com/viewtheme/?theme=vibration)

I would like the header part to stay the same size on all pages, the same goes for the footer. But as the body changes from page to page, I would like it to change accordingly but still fit properly to the header and footer part of the whole image.

The problem with this background is the fact that it not symmetrical, so the top & the bottom of the body image suppose to include the top & the bottom of the canvas *(the middle part of the image)*

I tried different techniques to implement this solution, but couldn't figure it out. The issue is that the body part of the image doesn't repeat-y so well, as it changes throughout the height of the image,

I would appreciate a solution, and it doesn't matter for me if I have to cut the images to a several parts.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to post this on [graphicdesign.stackexchange](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) instead of here, you'll probably get better feedback there. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/15981/9963 is a similar question, but yours will definitely need more work to get the effect you want since the perspective shifts between the top and the bottom of the page. Not sure if there's going to be a very good solution for what you want. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky, you can do something with `border-image`.

This CSS, for instance,

```css
body {
  width:100%; height:100%;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  border-width:63px 40px 133px 40px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:brown;
  border-image-source:url(http://webbos.co/vibration/wp-content/themes/vibration-child-theme/images/back1.jpg);
  border-image-slice:189 120 399 120 fill;
}
```

sets the borders to a fixed width (in this case 1/3 of the width of the sides in the image) and distributes the rest of the image over the body background.
Then all you need to do is position the header and footer on top of the border of the body...

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/R2FAg/).

Disclaimer: I've tested in Firefox and Chrome. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice) says it won't work on any other browser.